# How to use CONTAINS in sql with multiple conditions in WHERE

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM plot WHERE Status = '1' AND Show_Plot = '1' AND Area CONTAINS '$s_area' ORDER BY Date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

For this piece of code, error is given below!

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONTAINS 'lda'' at line 1

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to PHP (besides being widely open for SQL injection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM plot WHERE Status = '1' AND Show_Plot = '1' AND Area LIKE '%{$s_area}%' ORDER BY Date DESC";
```

Comment: No. Never propose that someone should use a query that is open to SQL injection

Comment: You are right absolutely, but his problem is syntax error and that’s what I was addressing.

Comment: If there is any syntax error, why didn't you mention that in your answer? That would help the OP to learn from it

Comment: It is mentioned in the question